# how to show last 5 images from the one post gallery

Tags: shortcode, gallery

i want to get the 5 images of a one post gallery and show this random,

> example : [gallery id="123" orderby="rand" {numberpost=1 } or offset
>   ? ]

*[[gallery] codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)*

tanks for help me.

Comment: i think to get parametric include id of images with offset , any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gallery-extended/

You'll be able to set how many images to show via this code:

```
[gallery link=file start=1 end=5]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes this is work , tanks

Comment: but this is show 5 image , i need to show 1 image by random order . you get it ?

Comment: finally i found it !      `[gallery link=file start=0 end=0 sortby="rand"]`